# Variable number of arguments function run time error

Tags: c++, function, vector

This is supposed to return a vector with all word1 arguments that contain sub as a substring but i keep getting the error
"line 779 vector subscript out of range"

```
vector<string> search(int num1, string sub, string word1 ...)
{
    va_list arguments;
    string pword = "";
    pword.assign(word1);
    vector<std::string> vec;
    vec.push_back(sub);
    vec[0] = sub;
    va_start(arguments, word1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < pword.length(); x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < sub.length(); y++)
            {
                if(y+x < pword.length())
                {
                    if(pword[y+x] == sub[y])
                        continue;
                    else
                        break;
                }
                else 
                    break;
                vec.push_back(pword);
            }
        }
        pword = va_arg(arguments, string);
    }       
    va_end(arguments);
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: No reason to use var args in c++

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you index into `vec`

Comment: just changed it now it does

Answer (score 1):

So you show this in your example:

```
vector<std::string> vec;
vec.push_back(sub);
vec[0] = sub;
```

You previously had the last line commented out:

```
vector<std::string> vec;
vec.push_back(sub);
//vec[0] = sub;
```

I'm betting that your *real* code, the code which didn't work, was this:

```
vector<std::string> vec;   
vec[0] = sub;
```

And that doesn't work because your vector has no elements.  Indexing into a vector does not create a spot for you.  It must be less than the size of the collection.  The size at that line is 0, so it doesn't work.

You can initialize the vector with an initial capacity:

```
const size_t count = 1;
vector<std::string> vec(count);
vec[0] = sub;  // works!
```

Comment: when i did that i had a ddifferent runtime error that was not a thrown exception from the vector class. This did bring me closer though thank you. something is printed

Answer (score 0):

Change the function prototype to:

```
vector <string> search (string sub, const vector <string> & words)
```

After that, things should fall into place quite nicely. Set up and empty `vector <string>` result. Iterate through words, finding the substring. When you find one, push the word into the result.

Return the result (always).

Comment: i have to use variable number of arguments

Comment: @user1767077 Why do you have to? Passing the vector is a much better design.